# Create new rows based on a value in a column

Tags: dataset, pandas, data-science-model, dataframe, python-3.x

My dateset is generated like the example

```
df = {'event':['A','B','C','D'],
     'budget':['123','433','1000','1299'],
     'duration_days':['6','3','4','2']}
```

I need to create rows for each event based on the column 'duration_days', if I have duration = 6 the event may have 6 rows:

| event | budget | duration_days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | 6 |
| A | 123 | 6 |
| A | 123 | 6 |
| A | 123 | 6 |
| A | 123 | 6 |
| A | 123 | 6 |
| B | 123 | 3 |
| B | 123 | 3 |
| B | 123 | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this is probably to first convert the dataframe back to a list of rows, then use base python syntax to repeat each row *n* times, and then convert that back to a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "event": ["A","B","C","D"],
    "budget": [123, 433, 1000, 1299],
    "duration_days": [6, 3, 4, 2]
})

pd.DataFrame([
    row # select the full row
    for row in df.to_dict(orient="records") # for each row in the dataframe
    for _ in range(row["duration_days"]) # and repeat the row for row["duration"] times
])
```

Which gives the following dataframe:

| event | budget | duration_days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | 6 |
| A | 123 | 6 |
| A | 123 | 6 |
| A | 123 | 6 |
| A | 123 | 6 |
| A | 123 | 6 |
| B | 433 | 3 |
| B | 433 | 3 |
| B | 433 | 3 |
| C | 1000 | 4 |
| C | 1000 | 4 |
| C | 1000 | 4 |
| C | 1000 | 4 |
| D | 1299 | 2 |
| D | 1299 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think your dataset have some problem because if you use single quote like this `'['1','2','3','4']'` in the value for the key then python will show you a syntax error.

So I will take the as below

```
df = {'event':['A','B','C','D'],'budget':['123','433','1000','1299'],'duration_days':['6','3','4','2']}
```

Then convert it to a data frame as your requirement.

```
data = []

for i in range(len(df['event'])):
    for j in range(int(df['duration_days'][i])):
        temp = [df['event'][i], df['budget'][i], df['duration_days'][i]]
        data.append(temp)

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['event','budget','duration_days'])
data_df
```

| event | budget | duration_days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 123 |
| 1 | A | 123 |
| 2 | A | 123 |
| 3 | A | 123 |
| 4 | A | 123 |
| 5 | A | 123 |
| 6 | B | 433 |
| 7 | B | 433 |
| 8 | B | 433 |

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake when I was typing the code